# Rows on current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to find the rows that are currently visible to the user, in a Datatables table.

By which, I don't mean the rows that are visible according to the current filter value. That's easy enough:

```
table.$('tr', {'filter':'applied'});
```

But that returns rows regardless of whether they are visible on the currently-selected page or not.  If the table has 100 records, the filter is passing 20, and the rows-per-page is set to 10, I need to get those ten.

This should be simple, but I'm not finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
table.$('tbody tr:visible').length;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. That said, my `table` value is a DataTables API object. Should it not be?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with to get the value in a specified column for each row, based on three specified numbers, `cellnumber`, `start`, and `end`, the latter two of which could be used in conjunction with a page number (i.e. Page 2, and each page has 10 items, therefore `var start = pagenumber * numberofpageitems` and `var end = (pagenumber * numberofpageitems) + numberofpageitems` results in a start of 20 and an end of 30.

```
var start = 5
var end = 9
var cellnumber = 1
var tablearray = $('#table tr').slice(eval(start-1),eval(end));
jQuery.each(tablearray, function( index, value ) {
alert("Row " + eval(index + start) + ", Cell " + cellnumber + ": " + value.cells[eval(cellnumber-1)].innerHTML);
});
```

If you want to get all of the `object HTMLTableRowElement` objects, just knock the `.cells[0].innerHTML` off of the end of the alert like so:

```
var start = 5
var end = 9
var cellnumber = 1
var tablearray = $('#table tr').slice(eval(start-1),eval(end));
jQuery.each(tablearray, function( index, value ) {
alert("Row " + eval(index + start) + ", Cell " + cellnumber + ": " + value);
});
```

Then you can change alert to variable or something else in order to meet your specific needs.
A JSFiddle example of this code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/o6j21gae/